# ReactJS CSS Class not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am still new in using ReactJS. I wanted to create a class for a specific form but it is not working

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import s from './style.scss';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bem-grid';
class OrderDetails extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <Row>
              <form class="orderform">
                <h3>Product Details: </h3>
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs={5}>
                      Product: <br />
                      Category: <br />
                      Sub Category: <br />
                      Price: <br />
                      Color: <br />
                      Breakdown: 
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                      test
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                <h3>Print Details</h3>
                  <Row>
                    <Col xs={5}>
                      Print Method: <br />
                      Position:   <br />
                      Length:   <br />
                      Width:  <br />
                      Colors
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
              </form>
            </Row>
          </div>
     );
  }
}
export default withStyles(OrderDetails, s);
```

and here is my code for my style.css file

```
.orderform{
    color: red;
}
```

with a simple code of this I am not sure why it is not working. Please do guide me on how to use class CSS in ReactJS

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace it with

```
return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <form className="orderform">
```

As JSX uses `className` not `class`, from the [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

> Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as `class` and `for` are
>   discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components
>   expect DOM property names like `className` and `htmlFor`, respectively.

Comment: not sure why it is still not working. I have also added import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

Comment: So inspecting the HTML, everything works as expected, it's just the missing class that is the issue