# Why would a React page look fine on Ubuntu browsers, but not Windows browsers?

Tags: windows, reactjs, ubuntu, react-bootstrap

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting this problem, so any general hints would help.

I created some simple React pages (front-end only; static; using create-react-app) on my Ubuntu machine. I'm creating an optimized build, them moving it online.

The page is here, if you want to see if it works in your browser: [static website](http://www.aphorism44.com/)

When I use my Chrome or Firefox browser on my Ubuntu machine, the pages and the React Components look fine.

However, when I use the Chrome or Firefox browser on my Windows 7 machine, the page does not work correctly. Specifically, none of the React Components, aside from the top-level one, are showing up, and what is showing up isn't being formatted with CSS properly (I'm using react-bootstrap for formatting).

This is the page on one of my Ubuntu browsers:

[web site working on Ubuntu browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbd2g.png)

This is that same site on Windows:

[web site not working in Windows browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA8CG.png)

There are no error messages in the console in either place.

I'm guessing there is something simple involved, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it could be. Any ideas?

NOTES

My Chrome version on Ubuntu is 63.0.3238.108 (Official Build)(64-bit). My Chrome version on Windows is  64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I placed the React Developer Tools as an extension on both versions of Chrome, and both state that "This page is using the production build of React. "

The extra components (not showing up in Windows browsers) are all accessed by a state change. Below is the full code for the page I've taken shots of:

NOTE - I did change "class" to "className," but the problem on Windows is persisting.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PageHeader, Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
import './index.css';

import HomePanel from './HomePanel';
import AboutPanel from './AboutPanel';
import BlogPanel from './BlogPanel';
import ProgramPanel from './ProgramPanel';
import GamePanel from './GamePanel';
import Footer from './Footer';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {key: 1};
  }
  handleSelect(key) {
    this.setState({key});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
        <PageHeader>
          <h1 className="mainHeader">Aphorism 44</h1>
          <h3 className="mainHeader">Playing Around with Code...</h3>
        </PageHeader>
        <Tabs onSelect={ (e)=>this.handleSelect(e)} 
activeKey={this.state.key}>
          <Tab eventKey={1} title="Home"><HomePanel/></Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={2} title="About"><AboutPanel/></Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={3} title="Blogs"><BlogPanel/></Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={4} title="Programs"><ProgramPanel/></Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={5} title="Games"><GamePanel/></Tab>
        </Tabs>
        </header>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After adding the React Develop Tools, I get the following Console error on both OSs, but the problems are only showing up on Windows:

**Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed.**

Comment: I have Ubuntu, so I see same like on Windows.... so problem not it windows browser

Comment: so.. it's definitely something about the way your bootstrap css is being loaded. still trying to figure out why some styles aren't being applied. notably `.fade` has opacity 0 which causes none of the content to appear. removing that style you can see the content

Comment: can you show the lines of code in your app that are relevant to loading css? like javascript imports

Comment: ohhhhhhhh are you using `class` not `className` ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS CSS Class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567803/reactjs-css-class-not-working)

Comment: Updated from "class" to "className," but no changes.

Comment: did you add support for less in your build step?

Comment: Both build and original are working locally on Ubuntu (where I built it), so am looking closer at browser issues.

Comment: Thank you AZIUM! That was it! Bootstrap LESS.

Answer (score 0):

Azium was correct about the LESS file.

I changed that to the regular Bootstrap CSS file, and imported that instead of the LESS file.

And it worked again.

I'm not sure why it broke to begin with, but it's okay now.